# How to automate running a command on Spark SQL or Scala Shell every 15 mins?

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark

I have some data in Cassandra that is dynamic and am running DSE 4.5 in spark analytics mode.

Since I cannot keep my RDD in sync with underlying database if I cache, I need to have some background process that continuously generates my RDD and collects latest from DB.

How can I automate such that I run the following every 15 minutes in Scala Shell? (I am new to scala)

1. Create an RDD from cassandra table A
2. Transform it
3. Save to a Cassandra Table B

Alternately, how can I automate such that I can run my "insert with select" command in shark/spark sql continuously every 15 minutes?

Comment: The Spark Shell is an interactive environment. I don't think that it is the right place to keep a background process running. Why this requirement?

Answer (score 2):

You could write an application and run a cron job to trigger it every 15 minutes. If you're on mesos, chronos may be of interest. Another alternative is to have a spark streaming application and either a) send a message to it, and have it insert into both tables or b) send it a notification via some messaging system (kafka / rabbit etc.) and trigger the work in response. This does take up a core for listening, and I'd see if the simple cron job can work.

Comment: I think the step up from _"I'm using spark-shell"_ to _"write an application"_ may be a bit steep. Perhaps you could include some pointers for that.

Comment: On the contrary, it's extremely simple :) Are you familiar with scala? Even if not, it's fairly straight forward - you don't need to know much about scala to use cassandra. Have a look at: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector . It's probably the easiest way to get what you need. You can even use Spark SQL with the connector.

Comment: It seems simple because you've done it so much. We'll see if it's simple for the OP. He may or may not be a programmer.

Comment: It's a form of encouragement. And of the various things I've programmed, getting spark + cassandra + scala going was quite easy. And I wasn't from the jvm world at all when I did it.